# Publish audio when already publishing video with Ant Media

Tags: webrtc, ant-media-server-sdk

I try to reproduce a classroom in which a teacher will publish video and audio and student only video at first.
Students can raise hand and teacher can accept to leave the student speak (all with dataChannel). I tried to change the `mediaConstraints` (enable `audio`) but as WebRTCAdaptor is basically stateless, it does not change a thing. Is there a simple way to publish audio as video is already published, as I cannot publish twice either.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a WebRTCAdaptor with a disabled audio, user would not be able to speak later.
But you can use the `Un/Mute mic funtions` for that. As an example:
`webRTCAdaptor.muteLocalMic()` would mute the microphone and `webRTCAdaptor.unmuteLocalMic()`
These functions are included in the sample conference.html file.
You can use these functions for your case.